# ¿como modificar una base de datos desde el Jtable?

Tags: java, netbeans

Hola buenas soy nuevo en netbeans ayúdenme,
necesito encontrar la manera de modificar datos de una `bd` directamente desde el `jtable` del `Frame` y validar los cambios presionando un botón.

metodo que use hace poco y no hace nada...

```
public void modificar(){

    Conectar conex = new Conectar();
    Connection con = conex.conectar();

        frmListar.tabla.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener(){
        @Override
        public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e){
               if(e.getType() == TableModelEvent.UPDATE){
                   String colname = null;
                   if(e.getColumn() ==0){
                       colname = "num_ficha";
                   }
                   else if(e.getColumn() ==1){
                       colname = "nombre";
                   }
                   else if(e.getColumn() ==2){
                       colname = "edad";
                   }
                   else if(e.getColumn() ==3){
                       colname = "vacunas";
                   }
                   else if(e.getColumn() ==4){
                       colname = "peso";
                   }
                   else if(e.getColumn() ==5){
                       colname = "altura";
                   }
                   else if(e.getColumn() ==6){
                       colname = "tipo";
                   }
                   else if(e.getColumn() ==7){
                       colname = "clasificacion";
                   }
                   else if(e.getColumn() ==8){
                       colname = "nom_duenno";
                   }
                   else if(e.getColumn() ==9){
                       colname = "fono";
                   }
                String sql = "UPDATE mascota SET "+colname+"="+frmListar.tabla.getModel().getValueAt(e.getFirstRow(), e.getColumn())+"WHERE num_ficha=?";
                Conectar conex = new Conectar();
                Connection con = conex.conectar();
                PreparedStatement ps;
                try {
                   ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                   int rows = ps.executeUpdate();
                }catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Registro.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
               } 
        }
        };
    });
}
```

Cuando cambio un dato en la `tabla` con este metodo y presiono el botón modificar todo va bien, pero al pasar con el cursor a otra celda salta el siguiente error y no se realiza ningún cambio:

> Dec 12, 2018 12:11:02 PM Controlador.Registro$2 tableChanged SEVERE:
>   null java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:988)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:974)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.checkAllParametersSet(PreparedStatement.java:2611)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.fillSendPacket(PreparedStatement.java:2586)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2432)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2375)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2359)
>     at Controlador.Registro$2.tableChanged(Registro.java:253)   at
>   javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel.fireTableChanged(AbstractTableModel.java:296)
>     at
>   javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel.fireTableCellUpdated(AbstractTableModel.java:275)
>     at
>   javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.setValueAt(DefaultTableModel.java:666)
>     at javax.swing.JTable.setValueAt(JTable.java:2741)  at
>   javax.swing.JTable.editingStopped(JTable.java:4723)   at
>   javax.swing.AbstractCellEditor.fireEditingStopped(AbstractCellEditor.java:141)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor$EditorDelegate.stopCellEditing(DefaultCellEditor.java:368)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor.stopCellEditing(DefaultCellEditor.java:233)
>     at javax.swing.JTable$GenericEditor.stopCellEditing(JTable.java:5467)
>     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI$Handler.mousePressed(BasicTableUI.java:1010)
>     at
>   java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(AWTEventMulticaster.java:280)
>     at
>   java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(AWTEventMulticaster.java:279)
>     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6530)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)    at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)  at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2238)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)     at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2296)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4897)
>     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4531)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4475)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2282)    at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>     at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Comment: no falta pasar el parametro para el numficha?

Comment: Como deberia hacerlo? pense que asi funcionaria.

Comment: WHERE num_ficha=? esto quiere decir que espera un parametro. no se como se hace para pasar parametros con lo que estas usando.. alguien te podra iluminar mejor.. pero ya tenes por donde ir averiguando...

Comment: pues si ya tengo por donde buscar al menos, gracias...  Por otro lado no conoces alguna otra manera de modificar un jtable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con el metodo addTableModelListener lo hice y aqui te dejo mi codigo espero te sirva, aca hay mas info [ejemplo de uso TableModelListener](http://chuwiki.chuidiang.org/index.php?title=Ejemplo_de_uso_de_TableModelListener)

```
modelo = new ModeloTabla(1);        
    tabla = new JTable(modelo); 
    tabla.getModel().addTableModelListener((TableModelEvent e) -> {
        if (e.getType() == TableModelEvent.UPDATE) {
            try {
                int fila = e.getFirstRow();
                int columna = e.getColumn();
                String idArchivo = tabla.getValueAt(tabla.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString();
                String textomodificado = tabla.getValueAt(fila,columna).toString();                                       
                String query = "update archivos set comentario = ? where idarchivo = ?";
                PreparedStatement preparedStmt = ConexionBaseDatos.obtener().prepareStatement(query);
                preparedStmt.setString   (1, textomodificado);
                preparedStmt.setString(2, idArchivo);                    
                preparedStmt.executeUpdate();      
                ConexionBaseDatos.cerrar();                    

            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Ventana.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }


        }
    } //metodo para cuando se agrega informacion a la tabla
    );
```

cada vez que se ingresa informacion a la tabla llama a este metodo automaticamente entonces aqui yo saque esa informacion y la ingrese a la bd. Tu solo tienes que guardar esa info y cuando se presione el boton enviar esa info a la bd